# Regex matching everything that's not a 4 digit number

Tags: regex, r

I match and replace 4-digit numbers preceded and followed by white space with:

```
str12 <- "coihr 1234 &/()= jngm 34 ljd"
sub("\\s\\d{4}\\s", "", str12)
[1] "coihr&/()= jngm 34 ljd"
```

but, every try to invert this and extract the number instead fails.
I want:

```
[1] 1234
```

does someone has a clue?

ps: I know how to do it with {stringr} but am wondering if it's possible with {base} only..

```
require(stringr)
gsub("\\s", "", str_extract(str12, "\\s\\d{4}\\s"))
[1] "1234"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to capture group in regex using `()`. Taking the same example

```
str12 <- "coihr 1234 &/()= jngm 34 ljd"
gsub(".*\\s(\\d{4})\\s.*", "\\1", str12)
[1] "1234"
```

Comment: Yup. We must've been typing the same lines at the same time... I just deleted that first attempt, and posted a second, better, solution which *does* extract the first match.

Answer (score 6):

`regmatches()`, only available since R-2.14.0, allows you to "extract or replace matched substrings from match data obtained by `regexpr`, `gregexpr` or `regexec`"

Here are examples of how you could use `regmatches()` to extract either the *first* whitespace-cushioned 4-digit substring in your input character string, or *all* such substrings.

```
## Example strings and pattern
x <- "coihr 1234 &/()= jngm 34 ljd"          # string with 1 matching substring
xx <- "coihr 1234 &/()= jngm 3444  6789 ljd" # string with >1 matching substring
pat <- "(?<=\\s)(\\d{4})(?=\\s)"

## Use regexpr() to extract *1st* matching substring
as.numeric(regmatches(x, regexpr(pat, x, perl=TRUE)))
# [1] 1234
as.numeric(regmatches(xx, regexpr(pat, xx, perl=TRUE)))
# [1] 1234


## Use gregexpr() to extract *all* matching substrings
as.numeric(regmatches(xx, gregexpr(pat, xx, perl=TRUE))[[1]])
# [1] 1234 3444 6789
```

(Note that this will return `numeric(0)` for character strings not containing a substring matching your criteria).

Comment: @JoshObrien : +1 nice use of `regmatches`

Comment: I've already gone with dickoa's answer.. Thanks a lot, though, for posting this approach +1!

Comment: Another option here is to use `\b\\d{4}\b` - it will also work if the number is on the start of the string. (however, it will also match other cases, like `"abc(1234)"`). Of course, the OP did say "preceded and followed by white space", so it may be useless `:P`

Comment: Thanks @Kobi! ..not useless at all: in fact I was keen to know how to handle the number if it is at the beginning/ending of a line..

Comment: @Kobi: where would I have to put the brackets for the backreference? I couldn't get it to work with: gsub(".*(\b\\d{4}\b).*", "\\1", str12)..

Comment: @Kay -- Try this out. It should work for substrings preceded by space or the start of the string, and succeeded by space or the end of the string: `pat <- "(^|\\s)(\\d{4})($|\\s)"; as.numeric(gsub("\\s", "", regmatches(x, regexpr(pat, x))))`

Comment: @Josh - Many thanks, this in fact seems to be the most suited/general approach! I tried it also with your example for extracting all 4-digits numbers, either inbetween spaces, at the beginning or end of a string and it works like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty naive about regex in general, but here's an ugly way to do it in base:

```
# if it's always in the same spot as in your example
unlist(strsplit(str12, split = " "))[2]

# or if it can occur in various places
str13 <- unlist(strsplit(str12, split = " "))
str13[!is.na(as.integer(str13)) & nchar(str13) == 4] # issues warning
```