# Extract instead of Replace string in R

Tags: r, string, string-matching

In this string:

```
q <- "2 t1, 1t23 xxx, 32t1, 4"
```

How can I elegantly extract and invert the structure `\\d+t\\d+` from `q` to get:

```
c("23X1","1X32")
```

I know it's very simple to replace it for the new structure using:

```
gsub("(\\d+)t(\\d+)", "\\2X\\1", q)
```

But I found nothing similar to perform extraction instead of replacement. I looked at base functions and in the `stringr` and `stringi` packages.

In `stringr` I almost get what I need with:

```
str_extract_all(q, "(\\d+)t(\\d+)")
```

but there is no option to manipulate the substring using something equivalent to `"\\2X\\1"`.

As a illustrative example, in `Mathematica` I can do that using:

```
StringCases[q, RegularExpression["(\\d+)t(\\d+)"]:> "$1$2"]
```

Any clue?

Here is a related post [Regex matching everything that's not a 4 digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115566)

Comment: Like `lapply(regmatches(q, gregexpr("(\\d+)t(\\d+)", q)), function(x) gsub("(\\d+)t(\\d+)", "\\2X\\1", x))`?

Comment: Just because it took me some time to find, here an alternative with stringr: `lapply( str_split( str_extract_all(q, "(\\d+)t(\\d+)")[[1]], "t" ), function( x ) paste( x[ 2 ], "X", x[ 1 ], sep = "" ) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(stringi)

apply(stri_match_all_regex(q, "([[:digit:]]+)t([[:digit:]]+)")[[1]], 1,
       function(x) x[3] %s+% "X" %s+% x[2])
## [1] "23X1" "1X32"
```

you can use your shorter digit class if you like, but I have gotten in the habit of using the POSIX-friendly versions.

Alternate `stringr` version (and uses `paste0` instead of the handy concatenation operator in `stringi`:

```
apply(stri_match_all_regex(q, "([[:digit:]]+)t([[:digit:]]+)")[[1]], 1,
       function(x) paste0(x[3:2], collapse="X"))
```